# How to create a aimLine in a pool game on unity2d?

Tags: unity, billiards

I want to design a Aim Line for my player in unity2d. The game is split screen so what I basically want is that whenever its my player turn I want my player which is a ball to cast a raycast like you see in pool/snooker/billiard games. [image: Reference].

This image is what I want. I have done some research and this image is also from other forum which uses Gl lines that seems a little complicated for me So what I have done is this.

```
   public LineRenderer lr;
public Transform rayStart;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Cast a ray straight down.
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayStart.position, Vector2.up);

    // If it hits something...
    if (hit)
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        lr.SetPosition(0, rayStart.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
   
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

so Now what I am trying to do is that I am not touching my player which I did using this [thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/194830/two-players-using-touch-control-simultaneously). Now I have added a game Object behind my player that will shoot a raycast which works like a cue. I dont know which way to go but current code on that object is

`

public LineRenderer lr;

```
private void Start()
{
     
}
void Update()
{
    // Cast a ray straight down.
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up);

    if (hit)
    {

        lr.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
    }
   
    
}`
```

Comment: How does the behaviour of this code differ from what you want? What is the next step you need help solving? [How have you tried applying existing tutorials or past Q&A to solve your problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbilliards%5D+predict*)

Comment: I have checked others and I dont think they match my problem. What I want is a gameibject (knob or whatever) behind my ball to cast a line like in snooker.

Comment: @DMGregory or what I want is https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/194830/two-players-using-touch-control-simultaneously/194841#194841 this object to have a trajectory of where its gonna go.